# DataGridHyperlinkColumn text color when highlighted

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a simple WPF application which displays reddit links in a `DataGrid`:

[image]

Notice however that the link in the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` isn't visible when a row is selected, due to the color of the link and the color of the row highlight.

What's a good way to resolve this? Change the link text color? Change the row highlight color?

If possible, please show your suggestion in terms of C# code as opposed to XAML as this application isn't using XAML. Otherwise, a XAML solution is fine; I'll just convert it to C#. :-)

For reference, here's the code used for the `Title` column:

```
var event_setter = new EventSetter()
{
    Event = Hyperlink.ClickEvent,
    Handler = (RoutedEventHandler)((sender, e) => 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((data_grid.SelectedItem as Link).Url);
    })
};

var style = new Style();

style.Setters.Add(event_setter);

var hyperlink_column = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn()
{
    Header = "Title",
    Binding = new Binding("Title"),
    ElementStyle = style,
    Width = 600
};

data_grid.Columns.Add(hyperlink_column);
```

Comment: can please post the XAML code for datagrid too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an implicit `Hyperlink` style to your `DataGrid`:

```
const string Xaml = "<Style TargetType=\"Hyperlink\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
                    "<Style.Triggers>" +
                    "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}\" Value=\"True\">" +
                    "<Setter Property=\"Foreground\" Value=\"White\" />" +
                    "</DataTrigger>" +
                    "</Style.Triggers>" +
                    "</Style>";
data_grid.Resources.Add(typeof(Hyperlink), System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as Style);
data_grid.Columns.Add(hyperlink_column);
```

Comment: I've added an answer based on yours which demonstrates the same approach but converted from XAML to C#.

Answer (score 2):

Pure XAML solution:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Width="180"
                                 Header="Url"
                                 Binding="{Binding Path=Uri, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Selector.IsSelected property of DataGridHyperLink Column can be used and when the selection on particular item changes you can update the style with trigger.

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Trigger.Setters>
                    <!--change the value for the property based on your needs-->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                </Trigger.Setters>
            </Trigger> 
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: It's not the `Hyperlink` that is selected. It's the row in the `DataGrid` which means that binding to `Selector.IsSelected` won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the answer provided by @mm8 converted from XAML to C#:

```
var data_trigger = new DataTrigger()
{
    Binding = new Binding()
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { AncestorType = typeof(DataGridCell) }
    },
    Value = true
};

data_trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)));

var style = new Style(typeof(Hyperlink));

style.Triggers.Add(data_trigger);

data_grid.Resources.Add(typeof(Hyperlink), style);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the answer provided by @mm8 converted from XAML to C# which uses some [extension methods](https://gist.github.com/dharmatech/38f8fa808faa2cca4b289015a72ea02d) to avoid intermediate variables:

```
data_grid.Resources.Add(
    typeof(Hyperlink),
    new Style(typeof(Hyperlink))
    .AddTrigger(
        new DataTrigger()
        {
            Binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { AncestorType = typeof(DataGridCell) }
            },
            Value = true
        }
        .AddSetter(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)))));
```